# How can I know if it's a new user or already he signed in before using Google Signin?

Tags: authentication, google-api, google-signin

I developed a simple angular application in which I have a google sign in button. I used **angularx-social-login**. if the user connect with his google account it will display information like name, email and photo.

My question is when the user connect how can I know if it's a new user or already he signed in before?

Comment: It is not related to Angular but with Google API. You can use the Google API to get the Google userId of the user and check it against your database.

Comment: Basically none of this code, or the question title is related to the actual question